# this.props.navigation conflict with this.props.data in Apollo

Tags: react-native, react-apollo, react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation for navigation in my app and also I use Apollo to connect to my server and get query, as you know I have to use:
`const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      navigate("NewScreen");

Also when I want to set query data I have to use:

```
render() {
    const {data} = this.props
    const {loading, allData} = data
```

but I get this error: " Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined." However, if I remove this line:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
```

there is no problem.

How should I use these two together?

Comment: `this.props.navigation` hasn't `navigate` key in it, it contains the navigation methods. What are you try to do? Push/Pop a screen?

Comment: I used StackNavigator.  If I don't send graphQL data to props. this.props.navigation works properly.

Answer (score 0):

[React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) and [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) are two different libraries.

The function `navigate` comes from the React Navigation library. If you're using React Native Navigation, you'll have to use [push](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/screen-api?id=pushparams) instead.